# Cancelling onBeforeUnload with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, addeventlistener, onbeforeunload, attachevent

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the `onBeforeUnload` event from being triggered in IE9+ when using links without hrefs.

I've set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stafffan/hh6pq/8/) here (a simplified test of a real scenario), which pretty much describes what I'm trying to accomplish. Whenever `onBeforeUnload` is triggered (ergo, when a link is clicked), the page background becomes blue. When using `attachEvent` I can easily `return false` to prevent that from happen. But when adding the link's click event with `addEventListener`, the return statement doesn't make any difference. More or less, I would like link 4 to behave like link 2.

Yes, changing from links to buttons would be a solution. Altering the onBeforeUnload functionality (like having that code as part och the click functionality) would be another. But sadly, I don't have control of those pieces of code.

So. Are there any way I can stop click events on links from trigger `onBeforeUnload` when set up with `addEventListener`? Or did MS remove this possibility when migrating from `attachEvent` to `addEventListener`, because it's generally a bad idea to prevent users from navigating away from a page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using addEventListener you can add a parameter to your listener function.
The parameter will contain the event which is fired (you can stop this)
Use `event.preventDefault()` assuming the parameter is called event.

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hh6pq/9/) as an example

Comment: My God! You're actually right. I was certain that I tried all sorts of e.preventDefault() and alikes. Feel a bit stupid now. Thanks a lot, pal!